# Merging tags: stft, short-time-ft

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms, retagging

My first tag question. I have just discovered that we have `stft` and  `short-time-ft` tags. Should we merge them under one denomination? I often see "short-term-ft" in the literature (the ordinal value is not always time).

So I propose `stft-short-term-fourier`, to enable the tag auto-completion. Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perfectly valid suggestion. I merged those together and added synonym as well. Since now we should be using `stft` only.

Comment: Do we have special threads for that? Seems to me that practice differs across SE sites